# Subquery in Where clause in Doctrine referencing outern Entity

Tags: doctrine-orm

How the following SQL:

```
select * from chapter c where (select count(p.id) from paragraph p where p.chapter_id = c.id) > 0;
```

Can be written in Doctrine, preferably with use of Query Builder?

The paragraph table has a `Many-to-One relationship` with the chapter.

**UPDATE**
This is not a duplicate. Here is a reference to the outern entity Chapter.

Comment: Vote retracted. Why don't you make a join instead of a subquery? It's easier.

Comment: @Veve What SQL exactly do you mean?